# react-router - redirect private page to login page doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

I tried to implement my app like [react-router auth example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config) but I have a problem that my routes don't stick in login page and It never show me the login page.

I made [a simple sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwvv6x8w8l) that demonstrate what i did before.
as you can see in my route.js I have:

```
const Routes = ({ location }) => (
  <Switch location={location}>
    {menuData.map(page => {
      return page.private ? (
        <PrivateRoute {...page} key={page.path} />
      ) : (
        <PublicRoute {...page} key={page.path} />
      );
    })}
    <Redirect to="/private" />
  </Switch>
);
```

which the last `<Redirect />` component always run and I don't know why?

try to change that `<Redirect to="/login" />` or `<Redirect to="/public" />`.

any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pathname` to redirect must be kept separate from the search query if you are giving an object to `Redirect`.

```
 <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: `/login`,
          search: `?returnURL=${path}`
        }}
  />
```

Or you could simply have

```
<Redirect
        to={`/login?returnURL=${path}`}
/>
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/01zkjx03pw)

Comment: you saved my day sir! thank you very much. what an idiotic mistake I made. thanks again.